# How to cancel the vba from running when there's sent in a colum

Tags: vba

I have the below and I want it not to populate invite if "sent" is in column L. The aim is not to have some invites sent twice, how can this be achieved?

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim Cell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For Each Cell In Worksheets("Scheduler").Range("H2:H50").Cells
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(1)

If Cell.Value Like "*@*" Then      'try with less conditions first
With OutMail
.MeetingStatus = olMeeting
.RequiredAttendees = Cells(Cell.Row, "H").Value
.Subject = Cells(Cell.Row, "I").Value
.Body = Cells(Cell.Row, "J").Value
.Start = Cells(Cell.Row, "E").Value
.Location = "Zoom Meeting"
.Duration = Cells(Cell.Row, "F").Value
.BusyStatus = 1.5 ' set as Busy
.ReminderSet = True 'reminder set
.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = "15" 'reminder 2 weeks before
.Display
End With

Cells(Cell.Row, "L").Value = "sent"
Set OutMail = Nothing
End If
Next Cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check `Cells(Cell.Row, "L").Value` for `sent` at first.

```
For Each Cell In Worksheets("Scheduler").Range("H2:H50").Cells

    If Cells(Cell.Row, "L").Value <> "sent" then

        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(1)

        If Cell.Value Like "*@*" Then
        '... Rest of your code

    End if

next Cell
```

This way only Rows where the Value in Column L is not "sent" get processed.